# node.js file with yaml header

Tags: javascript, node.js, yaml

I have some node.js script files which I need to add some sort of textual metadata to and read this metadata from another node.js application.
I tried to use commented yaml header like so:

```
//someScript.js
/**
---
Title: some script
Description: script which does some things.
Params:
  -param1
  -param2
---
**/

//actual script code..
```

And then use front-matter:

```
//app.js
var frontMatter = require('yaml-front-matter')
var results = frontMatter.loadFront('someScript.js');
```

But "results" returned all the code and the yaml inside the "_content" key and didn't parse the yaml properly.

Do you know of another way to implement this requirement? Or maybe another similar solution to the problem? In general the I want to get the script's name, params and description for display purposes.
It doesn't have to be yaml metadata - any textual metadata will do but I didn't find another reasonable option.

Thanks in advance!

edit: The javascirpt scripts files should be in a valid javascript syntax so I can actually execute them, and that's why I wrote the yaml code as comment

Answer (score 1):

The `yaml-front-matter` module is set up to read regular `.yaml` files, not JavaScript files that YAML front matter in the comments. So, let's say instead of `someScript.js`, we had `someFile.yaml`.

The content of `someFile.yaml` in this case would be:

```
---
Title: some script
Description: script which does some things.
Params:
  -param1
  -param2
---

Your YAML content.
```

You could now do something like this:

```
var frontMatter = require('yaml-front-matter');
var yaml = frontMatter.loadFront('./wow.yaml');

console.log(yaml);
```

The follow would be logged to the console.

```
{ Title: 'some script',
  Description: 'script which does some things.',
  Params: '-param1 -param2',
  __content: '\n\nYour YAML content.\n' }
```

If the content of your YAML code was some kind of code that you wanted to execute (which is perhaps why you had this front matter in a JavaScript file), then you could use a module like [safe-eval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/safe-eval) or Node's built-in [`vm.runInThisContext()`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinthiscontext_code_options) method.

Comment: Hi Steve, The YAML code isn't executable, but the rest of the file contents(the //actual script code.. line). The yaml-fring-matter library expects the yaml to be in the beginning of the file, but without comments this is not a valid javascript syntax

Comment: Yea, my suspicion is that with this particular library you can't have your cake and eat it to. The library itself can only parse what we might think of like blog posts or something that are purely content with no executable code. You _could_ use either `safe-eval` or `vmRunInThisContent` to take that static content in the `__content` property and execute it like it was valid JavaScript (which is technically what it is in your case). This is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me if I simply change it so it looks like is documented (not wrapped in comments and no filename comment at the top, also no newline before yaml starts)

```
---
Title: some script
Description: script which does some things.
Params:
  -param1
  -param2
---

//actual script code..
```

Logging the output of frontmatter.loadFront()

```
{ Title: 'some script',
  Description: 'script which does some things.',
  Params: '-param1 -param2',
  __content: '\n\n//actual script code..\n' }
```

Comment: Hi, This will in fact work, but the problem is that the script file must remain in javascript valid syntax so I can actually execute it, that's why I commented out the yaml header.

Comment: In that case I believe that the only solution is to request that this feature be added on the frontmatter repository or add it yourself and create a pull request. At least there is nothing that i know of that will do this in the way you want.